# How can I Set log's colors in a Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot

I tried to do this in my log4j2.properties file, but it doesn't work:

```
appender.console.layout.pattern =%highlight{%d{yyyy-MM-dd}T%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5level [%tid] [%l] : %msg%n%throwable}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=gray, TRACE= White, noConsoleNoAnsi=false}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you expand on "it doesn't work"? That is, is there an error message, or is the output different from what you expected? Either way, post the details so we can help you.

Comment: i mean that doesn't make any changes